# Constructive proof sought for a theorem of J. de Sousa related to Hall's Marriage Theorem

Tags: matroid-theory

The following is the finite version of Theorem 7 in the article by J. de Sousa, "Disjoint Common Transversals," *Combinatorial Mathematics and its Applications: Proceedings of a Conference held at the Mathematical Institute, Oxford, from 7-10 July, 1969* (D. J. A. Welsh, ed.):

Let $S$ be a finite set, $I$ a finite index set, $\mathcal A=(A_i:i\in I)$ and $\mathcal B=(B_i:i\in I)$ families of subsets of $S$.

For $J\subseteq I$, let $A(J)$ denote $\bigcup_{j\in J} A_j$.

A *transversal* of $\mathcal A$ is the image of an injective map $f:I\to S$ such that $f(i)\in A_i$ for all $i\in I$.  A *common transversal* of $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$ is a subset that is a transversal of $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$.

If $m\ge1$, then $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$ have $m$ pairwise disjoint common transversals if and only if, for all $J,K\subseteq I$, $|A(J)\cap B(K)|\ge m(|J|+|K|-|I|)$.

I know this will seem vague, but I am looking for a proof of this theorem that is constructive and more-or-less direct, akin to a constructive proof of Hall's Marriage Theorem one can find in the book by Bryant and Perfect, *Independence Theory in Combinatorics*, Theorem 4.1, [pages 68-70](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Independence_Theory_in_Combinatorics/ibL1CAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=independence%20theory%20in%20combinatorics%20algorithm&pg=PA122&printsec=frontcover).

By "direct," I mean I do not want a reduction to, say, copying the original families of sets and using Hall's Marriage Theorem on some other family.